# generate package-lock.json programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

Suppose I read a package.json file in as a string/json object.  is it possible to create a package-lock.json file programmatically?

for example, something like this:

```
const pkg = require('./package.json');
const pkgLock = generatePackageLock(pkg);
```

does anything like this exist or do I HAVE to use the npm cli to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs provided by npm, I don’t think it’s possible to create it programmatically.

This is what npm doc says

‘package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. ‘

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json